# ST_Distance loop

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, loop, function

I want to create a postgresql function which calculates the distances between random points who are stored in one table.

For the Table:

```
CREATE TABLE s_1(
id bigserial primary key,
the_geom geometry,
descr text
);
```

For the points:

```
INSERT INTO s_1(the_geom)
SELECT ST_MakePoint(round(random()*100), round(random()*100))
FROM generate_series(1,25);
```

Now I want to create a function which calculate all possible distances between the points and store them in an output table
e.g 1 to 2, 1 to 3,...2 to 3, 2 to 4,... and so on.
So the loop should look something like this

```
i = 1
n = max id
for i to n-1
     for j to n
       ST_Distance(id.i, id.j)
```

I'm a beginner with sql and not able to get a loop working so far.

---

Could you help me create my own function as well. I assume it should look something like this ?!?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DIST()
RETURNS 
CREATE TABLE Distance(
a.id integer,
b.id integer,
ST_Distance integer
);

AS
$$

INSERT INTO Distance(a.id,b.id,ST_DISTANCE)
SELECT ST_Distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) from s_1 a, s_1 b 
WHERE a.id < b.id;

$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

In the table I want to save the 1st id, the 2nd id and the distance between them..
Not sure if this is even close :-(

Comment: Your example output and code differ in terms of whether you want 1-›2 and 2-›1 or only 1-›2

Comment: I only need the distance once. So only 1->2 will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cross join, but filter out the duplicate pairs, like this:

```
select st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) from s_1 a, s_1 b where a.id<b.id;
```

The a.id < b.id filter gives you all the a->b pairs but filters out the b->a pairs.

Considering alpha-beta-soup's comment, the pseudo code for my answer would like like this:

```
i = 1
n = max id
for i to n-1:
    j = i + 1
    for j to n:
        st_distance(geom[i], geom[j])
```

alpha-beta-soup's answer is:

```
i = 1
n = max id
for i to n:
    j = i
    for j to n:
        st_distance(geom[i], geom[j])
```

which might also be what you want. The latter retains zero-distance pairs, the former doesn't. The result count in my answer is n(n-1)/2 and in alpha-beta-soup's, n^2.

Comment: Cross Join works fine :-).

Answer (score 1):

You want a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM table AS a
CROSS JOIN table AS b
```

There are two caveats. Make sure your geometries are projected (or use the geography data type). Make sure you know what you're doing with this Cartesian product; you will end up with lots of records in your output, so you should keep your original table small and think hard about whether you actually want to use a Cartesian product.